# Change scale of a diode - Circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

Can I change the diode size in a circuit using Circuitikz while preserving the scale of the other components?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit of a hack, but looking at the manual, chapter 8, "examples", I think you can do something like that (notice the `scope`):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,calc}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[
    ]
    \draw (0,0) to[diode] (0,3);
    \begin{scope}
        \ctikzset{bipoles/diode/height=1.4, bipoles/diode/width=1.4,}
        \ctikzset{tripoles/npn/height=2.0, tripoles/npn/width=1.4,}
        \draw (2,0) to[diode] (2,3); 
        \draw (5,2) node[npn](q1){};
    \end{scope}
    \draw (7,2) node[npn](q2){}; 
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

I found the name of the keys by looking at the files in the distribution directory of circuitikz, which on TeXLive on Unix is at 
`/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/circuitikz/`.

Comment: Heads up: things will change in future ;-) https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/218

Comment: What would be the definitions of width and height of the npn? Would they include the legs? I tried to run `\ctikzset{tripoles/npn/height=2.0, tripoles/npn/width=1.4,}` and the transistor width (my definition from base to collector side) is `1cm`. I don't quite get how the command make it `1cm` instead of  `tripoles/npn/width * bipoles/length = 1.4 * 1.4 = 1.96 cm`.

Comment: @internet Yes, it includes the legs and it's quite complex --- the definitions are from the first releases of the software and not even I am sure about how the size are calculated. The only thing you can bet on is that they are proportional to `bipoles/length`. Sorry... (notice that this answer of mine was from before I started maintaining the package)